# How to show something on frontend (Angular) when node app crashed

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I have developed an application in mean stack and there are some processes which took extra time to perform such as inserting thousands of data into mongodb.

It crashes sometime and the UI of the application left hanging in the middle.

Is there any way to overcome this and show some error message to user when app crashes.

Below is some code example :-

```
Upload.upload({
        url: '/api/uploadarchive',
        data: {file: file}
    }).then(function (resp) {
        $scope.progress = false;
        console.log('Success ');
    }, function (resp) {
        console.log('Error status: ' + resp.status);
    }, function (evt) {
        var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
        //console.log('progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' + evt.config.data.file.name);
        console.log('progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ');
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend using `$http` [interceptors](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http). Interceptors will help you to handle  errors in a generic way so you will not have to use error callback for each request separately. For example you can use `responseError` interceptor to check if response status of any request  is `404` and in such case redirect to an error page:

*define factory with your interceptors:*

```
yourAppModule.factory('myHttpInterceptor', function($q, $state, dependency2) {
  return {
   'responseError': function(rejection) {
        var status = rejection.status;
        if (status === 404) {
            $state.go('errorPage');
        }
      return $q.reject(rejection);
    }
  };
});
```

*and then register it inside your application `config`:*

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('myHttpInterceptor');
```

Comment: The above code actually is of ng-file select, so it uses its on promises object. But i get your idea of interceptors. Thank You.